# Does Cardano support Dynamic CNFTs?

Tags: nft

Can we use offchain data through something like ChainLink and channel it to CNFTs to have them change in real time accordingly? Have got a great idea for a dynamic NFT project, but just want to know it's possible on Cardano first.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use native Plutus smart contracts for that.

Imagine a contract that accepts an NFT, burns it and mints a new one, with new properties.

Comment: Is it still an NFT if you can burn and mint it at will?

Comment: Yes, as long as it keeps to be non-fungible at all time.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Think my idea might be a bit too ambitious for that. Unsure it's possible without a hell of a lot more knowledge than I have, or at all. Cheers.

Comment: Every real time change would require burning and minting, meaning multiple TXs back to wallets that own one, all needing to be accompanied with ADA from somewhere. Will need to rethink.